Cannot decrypt with node.js encryptedstring using openssl in bash (symmetric encryption)
I'm symmetrically encrypting data using node.js code, that I'll decrypt using the openssl command in a bash script.
I have encrypt/decrypt functions in both environments that work as expected, but encrypting in one and decrypting in the other seems not to work.
I tried to make sure the methods used are completely the same (using aes-256-cbc, 10000 iterations, encoding, ...) but methods are still incompatible.
Encrypt/decrypt in node:
const crypto = require('crypto');
const { Buffer } = require('buffer');

function encrypt(text, password) {
    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 32, 'sha256');
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    const result = Buffer.concat([salt, iv, Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64')]).toString('base64');
    return result;
}

function decrypt(encryptedText, password) {
    const input = Buffer.from(encryptedText, 'base64');
    const salt = input.slice(0, 16);
    const iv = input.slice(16, 32);
    const encrypted = input.slice(32);
    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 32, 'sha256');
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
    return decrypted;
}

> encrypt('mysecrettext', 'mysecretkey')
'YRJnPLMis7e4Gj9mFDjwNPAPW6xn2EnsqRx/rcuUilLxJNbjKTC6g7HIoOaWCvZp'
> decrypt('YRJnPLMis7e4Gj9mFDjwNPAPW6xn2EnsqRx/rcuUilLxJNbjKTC6g7HIoOaWCvZp', 'mysecretkey')
'mysecrettext'

Encrypt/decrypt in Bash:
$ echo mysecrettext|openssl aes-256-cbc -a -A -salt -iter 10000 -pbkdf2 -k mysecretkey -e|b
ase64 -w0
VTJGc2RHVmtYMTl5c3NsY0s5azBMZ2wzK1ZocjNNeUhKM0d5Yll0aUtFVT0=
$(echo VTJGc2RHVmtYMTl5c3NsY0s5azBMZ2wzK1ZocjNNeUhKM0d5Yll0aUtFVT0=|base64 -d)|openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -iter 10000 -pbkdf2 -k mysecretkey -d
mysecrettext

But decrypting node's output:
$ echo $(echo YRJnPLMis7e4Gj9mFDjwNPAPW6xn2EnsqRx/rcuUilLxJNbjKTC6g7HIoOaWCvZp|base64 -d)|openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -iter 10000 -pbkdf2 -k mysecretkey -d
error reading input file

What is missing for these methods to be able to decrypt each other's data?
Tried to make sure the encryption/decryption methods and parameters in both environments are correct counterparts
Update: (@Denel)
This works also in node
const crypto = require('crypto');
const { Buffer } = require('buffer');

function encrypt(text, password) {
    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(8);
    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 32, 'sha256');
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    const result = Buffer.concat([Buffer.concat([Buffer.from('Salted__', 'utf8'), salt]), iv, Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64')]).toString('base64');
    return result;
}

> encrypt('mysecrettext', 'mysecretkey')
'U2FsdGVkX18+fTvgLNXdePnaE3b/p+v5OXPOwx0euku7lUt3OpOS55ALFM5+FDMb'
> Buffer.from('U2FsdGVkX18+fTvgLNXdePnaE3b/p+v5OXPOwx0euku7lUt3OpOS55ALFM5+FDMb', 'utf8').toString('base64')
'VTJGc2RHVmtYMTgrZlR2Z0xOWGRlUG5hRTNiL3ArdjVPWFBPd3gwZXVrdTdsVXQzT3BPUzU1QUxGTTUrRkRNYg=='

I found I had to base64-encode the node output a secont time to translate U2FsdGVkX1 into VTJGc2RHVm, which my openssl command expects (ie. 'Salted__', twice base64-encoded).
And close but no cigar in bash :
echo $(echo VTJGc2RHVmtYMTgrZlR2Z0xOWGRlUG5hRTNiL3ArdjVPWFBPd3gwZXVrdTdsVXQzT3BPUzU1QUxGTTUrRkRNYg==|base64 -d)|openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -iter 10000 -pbkdf2 -k mysecretkey -d
WU�j9���������imysecrettext


No, that doesn't work that way! OpenSSL uses a special format (Salted__||). In particular, the IV is derived as well (but can also be explicitly specified/overridden with -iv ). In addition, the supported salt size is 8 bytes by default (but can be changed to a maximum of 16 bytes as of v3.2). Also, the -a option Base64 decodes the ciphertext, so that the ciphertext does not have to be explicitly Base64 decoded beforehand (however, -a -A is probably required due to missing line breaks).

I think the order and the implementation of your code do not match how the OpenSSL library does it.
For starters, when using the -salt flag in the OpenSSL library, it will include the Salted__ header at the beginning of your text. OpenSSL also expects this header when trying to decrypt with the -salt flag, and it does not seem to be included in your node.js implementation.
However, I am not sure if prepending the salt and the IV is what the OpenSSL library does as well, I was under the impression that only the salt is prepended, which would also be encoded into base64 (which your implementation also does not do)
I am not keen on the details, so you should take another good look at the OpenSSL documentation yourself.
Edit:
Good news, I had a lot of free time and looked into how the IV and key are generated. OpenSSL uses a custom "KDF" generator for their IV and key, the specific details of these seem to vary, but I found an interesting post that explains the idea behind it. Be careful though, it's an outdated post so it is not accurate in the details.
The bad news, this is not included in the nodes.js crypto library, but you are lucky, I wrote a working version for you (only decrypt, I think you can figure out the encrypt yourself :)).
function decrypt(input, password) {
    // Convert inputs to bytes
    const inputBytes = Buffer.from(input, 'base64');
    
    const salt = inputBytes.slice(8, 16);
    const encryptedData = inputBytes.slice(16); 

    const iterations = 10000;
    const keyLen = 32; 
    const ivLen = 16; 

    const derivedKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iterations, keyLen + ivLen, 'sha256');
    const key = derivedKey.slice(0, keyLen);
    const iv = derivedKey.slice(keyLen);

    console.log('password:', password);
    console.log('salt:', salt.toString('hex'));
    console.log('key:', key.toString('hex'));
    console.log('iv:', iv.toString('hex'));

    // Create a decipher object
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedData, null, 'utf8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
    console.log('decrypted:', decrypted)
}

This implementation differs from the answers in the post I mentioned above, but it gives the same output as the OpenSSL library! I tested using the -p flag, which outputs the salt, key, and IV used before de- or encrypting.
Output from OpenSSL:
$ echo "U2FsdGVkX1/drfR8wADgiQn8VgS8zYmI6UBIzXWOQos=" | openssl aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -a -salt -k "mysecretkey" -p -d
salt=DDADF47CC000E089
key=3BAD713C8B20E5C12C40870A27979321EB9E7EA4C7BE3EF7BC5219E03E1ED777
iv =6816DCD240F6E01D115136903B1558FB
mysecrettext

Output from the above code:
$ node test.js 
password: mysecretkey
salt: ddadf47cc000e089
key: 3bad713c8b20e5c12c40870a27979321eb9e7ea4c7be3ef7bc5219e03e1ed777
iv: 6816dcd240f6e01d115136903b1558fb
decrypted: mysecrettext

This was a big learning experience, also for me haha!

Is it even possible to create node.js encryped text that would be decryptable with openssl, and if yes, does anybody know how to exactly construct the encryption code?

I don't see how it wouldn't, you would just have to ensure that you include the "Salted__" header and a 8 byte salt (instead of the 16 byte salt you have right now). I don't see any reason that it would not work if you implement the same standards that the OpenSSL library uses

I updated the question with a new version of the encrypt function, using an 8 byte salt. Openssl comes close, but produces some gibberish before the decrypted text. I must admit I am poking in the dark, trying to produce a ciphertext that openssl can correctly decrypt.

You should not include the iv in your output, don't concatenate it in. The OpenSSL library can derive the iv itself. Changing to this should be it: const result = Buffer.concat([Buffer.concat([Buffer.from('Salted__', 'utf8'), salt]), Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64')]).toString('base64');

Ok, thank you for your insights, but openssl does not produce expected output yet.
error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:../providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:
Also, when modifying the node.js encrypt function (the way you suggested), I'm also trying to keep the decrypt function working. const salt = input.slice(8, 16); is obvious, and then probably const encrypted = input.slice(16);, but if no iv is extracted, how will const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv); look?

I made an edit to my answer, this should work!

Yes, it does, fantastic! Now, I've been trying to construct the node.js encrypt function to go with it, but no success yet. What's bothering me is that in the decrypt function, the iv is sliced from the derivedKey, but at encryption time, the randomly created iv is input for the KDF... Or perhaps I should try to mimic the Python function user Null displayed on the interesting post...

in your encrypt function, you do exactly the same as I did in the decrypt function. Derive a key with crypto.pbkdf2Sync(); (which only needs the password and salt as input) but now you create a key of length keyLength and ivLength, which should be 32 + 16. The first 32 bytes are your key, the last are your iv. The same process as during decryption, you just derive the key and iv from your salt and password combination.

Omg... got it. Will post an answer with the acompanying encrypt function, and accept yours!

For reference, this is the encrypt function to go with Denels decrypt (and compatible with the openssl commands in the original question):
function encrypt(plaintext, password) {
    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(8);
    const dkey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 48, 'sha256');
    const key = dkey.slice(0, 32);
    const iv = dkey.slice(32);

    console.log('salt:', salt.toString('hex'));
    console.log('key:', key.toString('hex'));
    console.log('iv:', iv.toString('hex'));

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    const result = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from('Salted__', 'utf8'), salt, Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64')]).toString('base64');
    return result;
}

My only concern: is this iv sufficiently unpredictable and unique? Since not generated random, but derived from password & salt...
